# Changing ids for classes breaks my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm not good with javascript and jquery but trying to study and make work some scripts :)
I have this script working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('#homepage-header');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  if (startchange.length) {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (scroll_start >= offset.top) {
        $("#nav-toggle em").css('background-color', '#ffffff');
      }
    });
  }
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('#cosafacciamo');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  if (startchange.length) {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (scroll_start >= offset.top) {
        $("#nav-toggle em").css('background-color', '#000000');
      }
    });
  }
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('#successo');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  if (startchange.length) {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (scroll_start >= offset.top) {
        $("#nav-toggle em").css('background-color', '#ffffff');
      }
    });
  }
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('#blog');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  if (startchange.length) {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (scroll_start >= offset.top) {
        $("#nav-toggle em").css('background-color', '#000000');
      }
    });
  }
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('#contatti');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  if (startchange.length) {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (scroll_start >= offset.top) {
        $("#nav-toggle em").css('background-color', '#ffffff');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Then i tried to simplify this script with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('.white');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  if (startchange.length) {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
        $("#nav-toggle em").css('background-color', '#ffffff');
      }
    });
  }
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('.dark');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  if (startchange.length) {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
        $("#nav-toggle em").css('background-color', '#000000');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Obviously i put .white and .dark classes where are ID's but this second script only works for the first two blocks (#homepage-header and #cosafacciamo) and then the nav-toggle doesn't change color anymore.

Why the first script works correctly and not the second one?
What am i doing wrong?

Please help! Thanks ;)

Comment: FYI: You only need one instance `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`, to wrap all the rest of the code.

Comment: Because `ids` target one element, classes target all elements of a class. You probably need something like `var startchange = $('.dark').eq(0);`

Comment: Nice clean code. As Blazemonger said,You only need one instance.  I recommend you the use of functions in order to make it more readable.

Comment: I'm sorry it's the first time i post on stackoverflow and i don't know how to post correctly. I have to do any change?

Comment: I'm sorry @Blazemonger but i don't know how to do for one instance...can you please post an example?

Comment: @Andy adding .eq(0) didn't work :(

Comment: @Sapikelio Thanks for your answer....i don't know what do you mean using functions to make it more readable... You mean the code?

Answer (score 0):

When you set `var startchange = $('.white')`, that jQuery object `$('.white')` contains several DOM elements, but the [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method only returns numbers for the first one.

To solve this, use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through each DOM element.

You can also use JavaScript functions to keep your code [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself). Try something like this (untested):

```
function doMyThing(startchange,color) {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  if (startchange.length) {
    startchange.each(function() {
      var offset = $(this).offset();
      $(document).scroll(function() {
        scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_start >= offset.top) {
          $("#nav-toggle em").css('background-color', color);
        }
      }); // scroll
    } // if
  } // doMyThing
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  doMyThing($('.white'),'#ffffff'); 
  doMyThing($('.black'),'#000000'); 
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry @Blazemonger but i can't make it work....every time i try to run this code my homepage becomes all white....I noticed }); under // doMyThing comment...but they're not closing anything and i don't know how to open this script...I'm so beginner :((